# TYPO3 typoscript condition without log error

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, tx-news

I am trying to make a condition which does not produces errors in the log.

Tried:

```
[request.getQueryParams() && request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1'] && request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news'] > 0 && request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news'] in [857,858,913,914]]
```

and

```
[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi/news') in [857,858,913,914]]
```

both give `Unable to get an item of non-array`

Comment: "in the log" does mean what exactly? I tried your (first) condition in a TYPO3 10.4.21 with PHP  7.4.26 and configured with "Development"-preset. It's matching - and does not log anything in "System -> Log" or `var/log/typo3_<hash>.log`.

Comment: @JulianHofmann thanks for checking. I found out they put a condition in a systemplate which caused the log entry. This question can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that an old condition still existed in a system template which caused the var/log/typo3_x.log entry. So the condition examples above are good.